# MySQL Workbench - Black bar covering line numbers

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Idk if its the version of Workbench or what but this black bar keeps covering up my line numbers?

[image]

Comment: Info about the version of MySQLWorkbench, and the OS it is running on is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing (MySQL Workbench 8.0.25) on Mac and have not been able to find a clear answer or bug report.

Workaround: try creating and deleting lines. It appears to be a display bug with how the small blue dots by the line numbers are displayed. When you do something to affect them (such as creating or deleting lines in your code), the lines off screen are often blocked out like in your screenshot, but it also makes the lines you currently see work properly again. Scrolling seems to make it block out again. Strange bug. Hope we get an update.

Comment: Please don't add Me too as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a comment, or start a bounty once you have enough reputation

Comment: I offered a "workaround". This post was literally the only result I could find online after researching a fix, and I do want to up vote it and contribute to the solution.

Side note: I can't upvote or comment. Every time I try to interact on stackflow, an admin immediately negates my contribution. Can't seem to get those 15 reps to be able to upvote or comment or interact in any useful way.